# data type argument cannot be null in data profiling viewer

Tags: sql-server-2017

I am new to Data Profile Viewer. I just created a package in SSIS which contains a Data Profiling Task Component. I am using the Sample database of Adventureworks2012 and I am creating an XML file through it using Employee table. But when I am trying to view the XML in Data Profile Viewer and selecting the Candidate profile Key it is showing me the below error:

**Drill down query completed with error: The error message is:
 System.ArgumentNullException: 'dataType' argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: dataType
   at System.Data.DataColumn..ctor(String columnName, Type dataType, String expr, MappingType type)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataProfileViewer.QueryDrillDownWorker.DoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataProfileViewer.DrillDownControlContainer.backgroundWorker_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)**

Anyone having a knowledge on this how to resolve it. I am not able to find on Google.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -2):

Try to add Polybase feature to your instance.

Comment: Go to installation, check if the Polybase feature is installed in your current instance. I had the exact same problem and this works for me.